# Successfully Creating Firebase User in Nuxt 3 App Despite "Invalid API Key" Error

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm developing a Nuxt 3 application and integrating Firebase for authentication. I've set up my Firebase configuration within a Nuxt plugin, pulling the Firebase API key from Nuxt 3's runtime configuration. The setup allows me to successfully create a user with Firebase (I can see a created user on the firebase side); however, I'm encountering an "auth/invalid-api-key" error despite the operation's success. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Other config...
  runtimeConfig: {
    firebaseApiKey: '', // Expected to be overridden by NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY env variable
  }
});
```

**plugins/firebase-auth.ts**

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { useRuntimeConfig } from '#imports';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: config.firebaseApiKey,
    // Other Firebase config...
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Setup for auth, firestore...
});
```

**The Issue:**

Even though I can successfully create a user (validated on the firebase end), I receive a `Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)` error. Attempting to directly use process.env within the plugin and incorporating dotenv to load environment variables eliminates the error but introduces browser compatibility issues with modules like path.

**Question:**

Why am I able to create a user with Firebase in my Nuxt 3 application despite receiving an "auth/invalid-api-key" error, and how can I resolve this error without resorting to workarounds that lead to browser compatibility issues?